# There are 2 identical receive values ​from a promise: in one case it works, in another it gives an TypeError: x is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the element search in my autotest and take the name from the list. My code works, everything is fine. But in autotest I use this code several times. Therefore, I decided to put it into a function and call it when I need to.
Code operates:

```
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("item")), 20000);
  let findItems1 = await driver.findElements(By.className("item"));
  let items1 = findItems1.map(async elem => await elem.getText());
  await Promise.all(items1);

  let currentItem1 = findItems1[findItems1.length - 1];
  await currentItem1.click();

  currentName = await currentItem1.getText();  // This string operates
  await Promise.all(currentName)
  console.log(currentName)
```

I infer the value of the variable from the function in which the promise lies. I can click on this item. But when I want to get a text value from a promise, the string "currentName = await currentItem1.getText()" throws an error. Although in my first code this line works. I don’t understand what could be the reason.

Code doesn't operate:

```
async function findCurrentItem(){
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("item")), 20000);
    let findItems = await driver.findElements(By.className("item"));  
    let items = findItems.map(async elem => await elem.getText());
    await Promise.all(items);
    let currentItem = findItems[findItems.length - 1];
    return currentItem;        
  }
 let current = findCurrentItem();
  await currentItem1.click();
 console.log(current, 1)    // console displays promise
 let currentName = await current.getText(); // This string doesn't operate
 await Promise.all(currentName)
 console.log(currentName, 2)   // console displays error
```

Error:

```
TypeError: currentItem.getText is not a function
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made findCurrentItem async function but don't await its result when using it.
Change to `let current = await findCurrentItem();`